# could not find implicit value for parameter env: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[utils.auth.DefaultEnv]

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I'm using a Silhouette v4.0 library with play framework 2.5.
And have been trying to write test code using play specs2.
But, I get the following error with my test class as below.

Error Message

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter env: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[utils.auth.DefaultEnv]
        .withAuthenticator[DefaultEnv](identity.loginInfo)
                                      ^
```

Here's the test class

```
package controllers

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.matcher._
import org.specs2.mock._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.mailer.{ MailerClient, Email }
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.inject.bind
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.test._
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api._
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.repositories.AuthInfoRepository
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util._
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers._
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import utils.auth.DefaultEnv

class TestControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  "case" in new Context {
    new WithApplication(application) {
      val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/api/test")
        .withAuthenticator[DefaultEnv](identity.loginInfo) // <-
      val result = route(app, request).get
      status(result) must be equalTo OK
    }
  }

  trait Context extends Scope {
    val identity = User(
      loginInfo = LoginInfo(..)
      ..
    )

    implicit val env = FakeEnvironment[DefaultEnv](Seq(identity.loginInfo -> identity))

    class FakeModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
      def configure() = {
        bind[Environment[DefaultEnv]].toInstance(env)
      }
    }

    lazy val application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .overrides(new FakeModule)
      .build
  }
}
```

There are some other test classes similar to this class are properly able to compile and execute.
It's kind of implicit problem with scope..
Therefore, I tried to import all the same as another test class which's able to compile properly. But, still unable to compile.
Missing some import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler states, you're missing an implicit value. Use the following, which is modeled after [one of Silhouette's specs](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/4.0.0/silhouette-testkit/test/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/test/FakesSpec.scala):

```
class TestControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  "the POST request" should {    
    "return an OK response" in new Context {
      new WithApplication(application) {
        val identity = User(LoginInfo(...))
        implicit val env = FakeEnvironment[DefaultEnv](Seq(identity.loginInfo -> identity))
        val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/api/test")
          .withAuthenticator(identity.loginInfo)

        val result = route(app, request).get
        status(result) must be equalTo OK
      }
    }
  }

  trait Context extends Scope {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it's a last resort to resolve this problem. But, faster to resolve it anyway. Thank you for your advice anyway.